# Activating Code for saving and printing by pressing shortcut keys ctrl + p

Tags: php, jquery

I am having a web page written in php, With in that page there is a Button for saving and printing that page.(Users information is saved and the web page is printed using that button) The problem which i am having is that the users are using Short cut keys to print that page or they are using the file menu to do the same due to which i am not able to store the required information. I want to activate my php code when user clicks on print option in the file menu or when he presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>

Comment: There are [printing events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events#Printing_events) but I don't know if any browser implements them. There are so many ways that it could be defeated that I would not bother trying.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with a little code of jquery

```
$('body , document').keyup(function(e){
 if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 80){
<?php 
//code
?>
}
});
```

Comment: Hmm.. The PHP code is executed on the server, and will therefore in this case always be executed. The javascript code could be run 10 years from now if the page is cached. Also, it will not work in Chrome.

Comment: What are trying to convey my  friend ? ,  spend some time and try to check again with ur browser :) its working

Comment: I have spent some time to test it, have you? The javascript does NOT work in FF26, Chrome31, MSIE10 or Opera18 on Windows with jQuery2.0.3. It doesn't work with `keyup` because the browser has already handled the event. And again:  The PHP code is running on the server when the page is sent to the browser, and the javascript is running when the page is loaded. You can NOT call the php code like that from the javascript.

Comment: calling js code form js file is not the only way , you cab call it from php file also 

<?php

echo "
<script>
function()
</script>
";
?>

or in html file directly in or with script tag in php file so many options are there dude !

Comment: From your answer and comments it looks like you don't understand the difference between the code that is running on the server and the code that is running on the client. The code in your answer doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: I do bro ! may be you are right if u get the ans do let me know and correct me about the code that is running on the server and the code that is running on the client . 


javascript for client 

php for server 

whats wrong here !